# MySQL database related

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
purchase_mis(id, user_id, total_purchased, date)
daily_purchase(id, user_id, product_id, paid_amount, purchase_date)
```

I have a CRON file that runs every night, it counts the daily purchase from the `"daily_purchase"` table and runs `insert into "purchase_mis"`.

For example:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS purchase_count,
    purchase_date
FROM daily_purchase
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This returns the `purchase_count` for every user and then it will be inserted to the `"purchase_mis"` table.

```
INSERT INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
VALUES
    ('2', 'purchase_count', 'purchase_date');
```

But before inserting, it needs to check if the purchased information of `user_id = 2` for some date "`purchase_date`" has already been inserted so it should not be inserted again.

I want something like the below query:

```
INSERT INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
VALUES
    ('2', 'purchase_count', 'purchase_date')
WHERE date NOT EXISTS (SELECT date FROM purchase_mis WHERE user_id = '2');
```

Comment: Don't use character literals for numbers.`'2'` is a character, not a number. If `user_id` is defined as e.g. an integer, you should be using `2` - no single quotes around the value.

Answer (score 3):

Create a key on the date column, and then use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.  See this for more: ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Also, you can probably use triggers or procedures instead of a cron job; might make life a bit easier.

Comment: I think triggers are the appropriate technique

Comment: I cant use TRIGGER, because database structure is not that good.

Comment: @XiKam: what about procedures?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into purchase_mis
   (user_id, total_purchased, date)
select * 
from (
   select 2 as id, 
          100 as user_id, 
          str_to_date('2012-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d') as purchase_date
) t 
where not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM purchase_mis pm
                  WHERE pm.user_id = t.id 
                  and pm.date = t.purchase_date);
```